# C++ pointers prints out the memory address and not numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

I really can't understand why this prints out the memory address and not the say {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} if you input 5. How can I fix this? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

        int columnInput;
        //int rowInput;

        int** column = NULL;


        cin >> columnInput;

        column = new(int*[columnInput]);

        for (int i = 0; i < columnInput; i++) {
            column[i] = new(int[i + 1]);
        }

        cout << "  |";
        for (int i = 0; i < columnInput; i++){
            cout << setw(3) << column[i] << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Because `column[i]` is a pointer. (which you just set five lines earlier with `column[i] = new(int[i + 1]);`). There is no stream insertion overload for `int*`, so the address is all you get.

Comment: You pass a pointer to the `<<` operator, it prints a pointer. There is no builtin method that prints an array. If you need one, you have to write one.

Comment: But first do the first thing you need: ditch pointers and arrays, and learn to use std containers.

Comment: You should use `std::vector` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you are looking for a 1D or a 2D dynamic array is not very clear from your code. The pointer-to-pointer variable and the commented out `rowInput` hint towards the latter, however using simple (i.e. not nested) for loops points to the former. In the case you want a 1D dynamic array, **Learner**'s answer is probably what you're looking for. Otherwise, take a close look at this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    // I don't really like this, because it can easily lead to name clashes.
    // If you really want it, not putting it in global scope is a good idea.
    using namespace std;

    int ** matrix = 0;

    int rows;
    int cols;

    cin >> rows;
    cin >> cols;

    // The convention is that the first dimension denotes the number of rows.
    // As an exercise, you can try to do the same with columns first.
    matrix = new int * [rows]; // reserve pointers for all rows

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[cols]; // reserve space for each row
    }

    // In order to access a 2D array you typically need nested for loops.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j ++) {
            matrix[i][j]  =             0;
            matrix[i][j] += (i % 10) * 10; // <- try commenting this out
            matrix[i][j] +=  j % 10  +  1; // <- same with this here
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    // Same here.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j ++) {
            cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j] << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Don't forget to do cleanup!
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] matrix;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/nvibct)

As others mentioned, since this is C++, using `std::vector` is a better option here. [This nice article](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17108/) over at cplusplus.com explores this and other options.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing a pointer.  How could `operator<<` possibly know how many elements the pointer points to? It can't  If you want to print the contents of an array or what a pointer points to then you'll have to write that yourself.

Comment: I really don't understand... how can I fix it?

Comment: @TMalo first explain what you are trying to do, it's not clear from your post. (Edit your post)

Comment: Ok sorry, so the idea is that I want to dynamically set a memory to an array and bypass defining a value in i.e #define SIZE 5. There is a idea in C that uses malloc to do this but I am trying to do it in C++. 
In other words set an arrays memory on the fly by user input. I can get it to print x amount of spaces but it prints the memory locations and not the numbers i.e 1 2 3 4 5 say if you input 5.

Comment: @T.Malo It's C++. You shouldn't use it as if it were C, because it isn't C. Use `std::vector` to hold your array.

Answer (score 0):

Because `column` is a pointer to pointer to integer..`int** column = NULL` printing `column` directly would give you address instead of integer values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate dynamic memory according to the user input and want to print it's content use this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int columnInput;
    int* column = NULL;

    cin >> columnInput;

    column = new int[columnInput];

    for (int i = 0; i < columnInput; i++) {
        column[i] = i;
    }

    cout << "  |";
    for (int i = 0; i < columnInput; i++){
        cout << setw(3) << column[i] << "|";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print a pointer's value, you have to put a * before the variable. This says to the compiler "Hey, here comes a pointer, give to me what is pointing at"

So, if ptr is a pointer, for example

```
*int ptr;
```

if you want to print ptr's value:

```
cout << *ptr;
```

This logic applies to every variable in C/C++.

If you have

```
int*** listOfListsOfListsOfInts;
```

And you want to print what's pointing at,

```
cout << ****listOfListsOfListsOfInts;
```

Whit a wildcard behind a variable, you get what a pointer is pointing at instead of the memory address that pointer is holding.